# mx.rpc classes in Actionsscript mobile project?

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, starling-framework

I'm in the process of evaluating the Feathers UI framework as a replacement for our current Flex mobile app (there are just too many limitations of Flex, mostly concerned with performance on retina devices) and coming from Flex, there are some issues I have with a pure AS project.

One big issue seems to be the use of web services. I frequently use mx.rpc classes and interfaces such as `IResponder`, `AsyncToken`, and `HTTPService`, which obviously aren't available without the Flex SDK.
How come that this isn't part of AIR and remains part of the Flex SDK and how do I get rid of this issue? Are there equivalents or do I have to make a hack and import the corresponding SWCs manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a non-Flex project that needs to communicate with a web service, you need two files from the Flex framework: rpc.swc and framework.swc.

You just add the SWCs to your project the same way you would any other SWCs. No MXML, no hacking necessary. I've used them in Flash CS projects and FlashDevelop AS3 projects.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I mean with "hack". But I'm using it for a couple of days now and it really works as expected. Seems to be the only solution then. Still wondering why Adobe doesn't add them to the AIR SDK, cause the basic URLLoader AIR provides simply doesn't cut it for a lot of use cases.